# Pagination issues with table format

Tags: php, pagination

Can anyone assist me out there. I am trying to solve this issues.
my table was a formerly a normal table and i use below codes to call the values on the statement table and it work perfectly for me, but I am trying to convert the normal tables to a pagination tables as shown below the line drawn

NORMAL TABLE = WORK PERFECTLY

```
<td data-title="Trns Date">'.$row["tdate"].'</td>  
     <td data-title="Description">'.$row["comments"].'</td>  
    <td data-title="Debit" class="numeric"><?php echo $tx_type == "debit" ? "$&nbsp;" . number_format($amount, 2) : ""; ?></td>
     <td data-title="Credit" class="numeric"><?php echo $tx_type == "credit" ? "$&nbsp;" . number_format($amount, 2) : ""; ?></td>
    ================================================================================PAGINATION TABLES:
```

But Now i trying to convert it to a pagination table due to the large database, i now use the below code to echo the value on the table.
it does not gives me any error on the table, but the value does not show. It just leaves space blank.

The last two rows for amount does not show.

```
<td>'.$row["tdate"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["comments"].'</td>  This two rows work ok
```

But the last two rows for amount values does not show the figures it was blank

```
<td>'.$row["tx_type == debit ? &nbsp; . number_format($amount, 2)"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["tx_type == credit ? &nbsp; . number_format($amount, 2)"].'</td>
```

Comment: Where do you get `$tx_type` and `$amount` variables? It seems that problem in the loop iteration in which you calculate this variables.

Comment: `tx_type, debit, credit` are no php variables so it would result everytime in false. Did you forget the `$` Or is this just in your lower example ?

Comment: Tx is the transaction type which i choose from the database. In the database I have debit and credit transaction type in one column.

Comment: Tx is the transaction type which i call from the database. 
In the database I have debit and credit transaction type in one column. so for me to call the transaction type on the account statement i use:

<td data-title="Debit" class="numeric"><?php echo $tx_type == "debit" ? "$&nbsp;" . number_format($amount, 2) : ""; ?></td> which work perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you are trying to decide the transaction type within the array key string.

Perhaps these two lines can help:

```php
<td>' . ($row["tx_type"] == 'debit' ? '&nbsp;' . number_format($row['amount'], 2) : "") . '</td>
<td>' . ($row["tx_type"] == 'credit' ? '&nbsp;' . number_format($row['amount'], 2) : "") . '</td>
```

Also I assumed the `amount` is also stored within the `$row`; if it is intended to be static similarly as in your example, just replace `$row['amount']` with `$amount` and you are set.

This snippet assumes you are iterating over an array like this:

```
$rows = [                                                                       
    array('tx_type' => 'credit', 'amount' => 123345.697),                       
    array('tx_type' => 'debit', 'amount' => 796543.21),
    //... and so on                         
];
```